# Replace links with the same class with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm looking for a way to replace 18 links using jQuery.

What I have is this:

```
    <a class="PDF-link" href="http://domain/0101_xxx.pdf" target="_blank">folder 1</a>
    <a class="PDF-link" href="http://domain/0102_xxx.pdf" target="_blank">folder 2</a>
    <a class="PDF-link" href="http://domain/0201_xxx.pdf" target="_blank">folder 2</a>
    <a class="PDF-link" href="http://domain/0202_xxx.pdf" target="_blank">folder 2</a>
    14 more like this
```

and I started with this jQuery:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
         var client  =  "<%=UserController.GetCurrentUserInfo().Username%>";
         $('.PDF-link').prop('href', $('.PDF-link').prop('href').replace('xxx', client));
    });
```

But that generates the same URL for each link:

```
    http://domain/0101_johndoe.pdf
    http://domain/0101_johndoe.pdf
    http://domain/0101_johndoe.pdf
    http://domain/0101_johndoe.pdf
```

and I'd like it to be like this:

```
    http://domain/0101_johndoe.pdf
    http://domain/0102_johndoe.pdf
    http://domain/0201_johndoe.pdf
    http://domain/0202_johndoe.pdf
```

Can someone help me out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The logic you're using won't work because each time you select the entire group of `.PDF-link` elements as a whole. Instead you can provide a function to `prop` which will be executed for each individual element found:

```
var client = "<%= UserController.GetCurrentUserInfo().Username %>";
$('.PDF-link').prop('href', function(i, val) {
    return val.replace('xxx', client);
});
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/rsds0cmm/)

Answer (score 1):

I'd use each in this case:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var client  =  "<%=UserController.GetCurrentUserInfo().Username%>";

    $('.PDF-link').each(function() {
        $(this).attr('href', $(this).attr('href').replace('xxx', client));
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `this.href` in a each for instead of `$('.PDF-link').prop('href')` 
[Example JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cecdcv8o/4/)

Answer (score -1):

try the below

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     var client  =  "<%=UserController.GetCurrentUserInfo().Username%>";
     $('a.PDF-link').prop('href',  client);
});
```

(or using attr)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     var client  =  "<%=UserController.GetCurrentUserInfo().Username%>";
     $('a.PDF-link').attr('href',  client);
});
```

(or using javascript this should work)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     var client  =  "<%=UserController.GetCurrentUserInfo().Username%>";
     $('a.PDF-link').each(function(){
        $(this)[0].setAttribute('href',  client);
     });
});
```

Comment: This will change all links for the client's name, and that's not what the OP wants.

Comment: whos OP and the one who asked question didn't said anything like there are even other elements with the same class even if there is a simple change in the jQuery selector will do the job

Comment: Using your suggestion, all 18 links would have the same thing (what's in the var client). You should read the question more carefully.

Comment: i suggest you read the question again because that's what the user want change, all the 18 links.And in the "var client" the value comes from the server

Comment: "But that generates the same URL for each link and I'd like it to be like this". Yes, he wanted to change all links, but not to the same thing.